# The height of a div extending to height of parent div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, height

On This webpage http://wuwoclientlindsay.wuwomedia.com/activelist_demo/

The div .slider-box is extending to height of parent div. I want to make it smaller. It doesnt seem to be a css effect, so I am thinking it is a js effect but I cant figure out what is causing it and the best way to adjust it.

```
<div class="slider-box">            
    <h2>Find Activities for Kids in Hertfordshire</h2>
        <form method="GET" action="pet-sitters/pet-sitter-jobs/">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" id="search_location" class="form-control" name="search_location" placeholder="Any location in Hertfordshire ">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Search</button>
            </div>                  
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please include the code block your are talking about to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked that website and I've noticed that there is an easy fix

```
.slider-box {
    position: absolute;
    left: auto;
    right: 24px;
    bottom: 24px;   <!-- REMOVE THIS OR CHANGE MAKE IT bottom: auto !important; -->
    top: 24px;
    width: 344px;
}
```

If you set position to absolute and set both bottom and top, it scales content size to fit into it.

That will do the trick.

Comment: Worked perfectly once I worked out which control panel to add the CSS to :)